# Why are .NET service packs installed when .NET is not on the machine?

Tags: .net

I have noticed this a few times when installing a Windows XP virtual machine.

On a clean copy of Windows XP Microsoft Update installs the service packs for .NET, for example .NET 2.0 SP2 is installed. However this seems to only partially install .NET and has caused problems for me with IIS/ASP.NET in the past.

There is an error when you try to install .NET manually so to resolve the problem I had to go to Add/Remove programs, uninstall the .NET service packs, install the real .NET framework, then reinstall the service packs.

Why are the service packs seemingly installed before .NET is even on the machine?

I have the feeling it may relate to how the framework handles the side-by-side versions that are installed. I hope it is something that I am misunderstanding about .NET rather than the service pack installer not checking for dependencies by mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, 3.5SP1 is the full .NET runtime for 3.5 with SP1 bits included and I will assume the same for 2.0 of the framework.

As for your IIS/ASP.NET features not being enabled, you may just need to run aspnet_regiis -iru in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 with a Windows Update (WU) .NET framework install (if you are enabling *after* you have the .NET bits installed that is)

The default-behind-the-scenes-WU-install may not auto-magically register with IIS.